# Error 500 on php for loop

Tags: php, mysql, imap

I am making a little script that read emails from my inbox and save them in a mysql database.

I have a php that check emails and save them to DB, and break the FOR if it ran for more than 1 second,   and I have an ajax script that call the php every time it stops.

so here is the ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
chequearCorreo(1);
});

function chequearCorreo(inicio){
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'inc/a.php',
  data: {mailInicio: inicio},
   success: function(data) {
       resultado = data.split("/");
       if(resultado[0]!=resultado[1]){
           //aun no termino
           chequearCorreo(resultado[0]);
       }
       $("body").html(data);

    },
    error: function(data){

    },
 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
 dataType: 'html'
});
}
</script>
```

and here is the php

```
session_start();
include 'coneccion-base-mails.php';

$crear_tabla_web =
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS web  
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
uid int,
carpeta VARCHAR(200),
fecha DATETIME,
remitente VARCHAR(200),
destinatario VARCHAR(200),
cc VARCHAR(200),
cco VARCHAR(200),
asunto VARCHAR(200),
body TEXT,
adjuntos VARCHAR(200),
leido VARCHAR(20),
flaged VARCHAR(20),
respondido VARCHAR(20),
reenviado VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)';
$mysqli->query($crear_tabla_web);

//FUNCION GUARDAR MAIL!!!

function guardarMail($uid,$carpeta,$fecha,$remitente,$destinatario,$cc,$cco,$asunto,$body,$leido,$flaged,$respondido,$reenviado){
global $mysqli;
//primero chequeamos que el mail no exista ya en la base
if ($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM web WHERE uid=".$uid."")){
    if( $result->num_rows == 0 ){
        //guardamos el post
        $fecha = strtotime($fecha);
        $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $fecha);

        $cons  = "INSERT INTO web (uid,carpeta,fecha,remitente,destinatario,cc,cco,asunto) VALUES (".$uid.",'".$carpeta."','".$fecha."','".$remitente."','".$destinatario."','".$cc."','".$cco."','".$asunto."')";
        $mysqli->query($cons);
    }
}
}
//fin guardar mail

$hostname = '{localhost:143}Inbox';
$username = '##########';
$password = '###';


$tiempoInicio = microtime(true);
/* Intento de conexión */
$conn = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('No se pudo conectar con: usuario: '.$username.' y clave: '.$password.' ' . imap_last_error());

$numMsg = imap_num_msg($conn);

for($i=$mailInicio;$i<=$numMsg;$i++){

$header = imap_header($conn,$i) ;
$fromInfo = $header->from[0];
$replyInfo = $header->reply_to[0];
$toInfo = $header->to[0];
$ccInfo = $header->cc[0];
$bccInfo = $header->bcc[0]; 

$detalles = array(
    "mailRemitente" => (isset($fromInfo->mailbox) && isset($fromInfo->host))
        ? $fromInfo->mailbox . "@" . $fromInfo->host : "",
    "nombreRemitente" => (isset($fromInfo->personal))
        ? $fromInfo->personal : "",
    "mailDestinatario" => (isset($toInfo->mailbox) && isset($toInfo->host))
        ? $toInfo->mailbox . "@" . $toInfo->host : "",
    "nombreDestinatario" => (isset($toInfo->personal))
        ? $toInfo->personal : "",
    "mailRespuesta" => (isset($replyInfo->mailbox) && isset($replyInfo->host))
        ? $replyInfo->mailbox . "@" . $replyInfo->host : "",
    "nombreRespuesta" => (isset($replyTo->personal))
        ? $replyto->personal : "",
    "mailCc" => (isset($ccInfo->mailbox) && isset($ccInfo->host))
        ? $ccInfo->mailbox . "@" . $ccInfo->host : "",
    "nombreCc" => (isset($ccInfo->personal))
        ? $replyto->personal : "",
    "mailCco" => (isset($bccInfo->mailbox) && isset($bccInfo->host))
        ? $bccInfo->mailbox . "@" . $bccInfo->host : "",
    "nombreCco" => (isset($bccInfo->personal))
        ? $bccInfo->personal : "",
    "asunto" => (isset($header->subject))
        ? $header->subject : "",
    "fecha" => (isset($header->udate))
        ? $header->udate : ""
);

$uid = imap_uid($conn,$i);
guardarMail($uid,'Inbox',$detalles["fecha"],$detalles["mailRemitente"],$detalles["mailDestinatario"],$detalles["mailCc"],$detalles["mailCco"],$detalles["asunto"],'','','','','');

$tiempoActual = microtime(true);

$deltaTiempo = $tiempoActual - $tiempoInicio;


if($deltaTiempo > 1 ){


    break;

}



}
echo $i.'/'.$numMsg;
```

the problem is that the script runs for about 5 times, but at somepoint the ajax can't load the php anymore, it gives error 500

Comment: look at your server's error log. details about the 500 will be there, most likely. And you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Without any kind of rest or pause in your code, you actually may be running up against either a server time out or a refusal of service. Just because you are using the IMAP protocol doesn't mean you can just slam a server with requests and expect everything to come back. Also, like @MarcB said, the answer will most likely be in your server log, unless you are logging the connection to your email server somewhere else.

Comment: I can't find the data on the log, I have a line, where it says the file that failed (the php), the port, an ip, and the browser data (Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/2 etc  etc)

Comment: the_pete, what you mean with slaming the server??, I have 5000 mails on inbox and want to get the headers of all mails. the hosting company don't give an anwser, they say they don't attend script problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tech support of the hosting changed php version from 5.2 to 5.3 and now it works. It works and seems to run faster.